# How to override BACKOFF_MAX while working with requests retry

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I am using requests module with python3 to implement Retry mechanism on failure.

Following is my code-

```
session = session or requests.Session()
retry = Retry(
    total=retries,
    read=retries,
    connect=retries,
    backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
    status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    method_whitelist=method_whitelist)
retry.BACKOFF_MAX = 60
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount(BASE_URL, adapter)
return session
```

I do not see any named argument to set maximum backoff (BACKOFF_MAX in Retry class). I do not want sleep time between retries more than 60 seconds. 
How can I achieve it? Resetting BACKOFF_MAX doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by overriding get_backoff_time() of Retry class

```
class RetryRequest(Retry):

    DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST = frozenset([
    'HEAD', 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE'])

    def __init__(self, total=10, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None,
             method_whitelist=DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST, status_forcelist=None,
             backoff_factor=0, raise_on_redirect=True, raise_on_status=True,
             history=None, respect_retry_after_header=True, max_backoff=60):
        super(RetryRequest, self).__init__(total=total, connect=connect, read=read, redirect=redirect, status=status,
             method_whitelist=method_whitelist, status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
             backoff_factor=backoff_factor, raise_on_redirect=raise_on_redirect, raise_on_status=raise_on_status,
             history=history, respect_retry_after_header=respect_retry_after_header)
        self.backoff_max = max_backoff

    def get_backoff_time(self):
    """ Formula for computing the current backoff
    :rtype: float
    """
        # We want to consider only the last consecutive errors sequence (Ignore redirects).
        consecutive_errors_len = len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x.redirect_location is None,
                                                reversed(self.history))))
        if consecutive_errors_len <= 1:
            return 0

        backoff_value = self.backoff_factor * (2 ** (consecutive_errors_len - 1))
        return min(self.backoff_max, backoff_value)
```

and using this class instead of Retry

```
session = session or requests.Session()
retry = RetryRequest(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
        method_whitelist=method_whitelist,
        max_backoff=max_backoff # in my case 60
)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount(BASE_URL, adapter)
return session
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my trick to have the behaviour that **I wanted**:

```
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry

class RetryRequest(Retry):
    BACKOFF_MAX = 77
```

Pros:

- You do not have to override any methods of Retry (urllib3.util.retry)

Cons:

- Not a real parameter

Other answers seem to deal with the "real parameter" situation. But, you also have to override the `new()` methods:

```
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry

class RetryRequest(Retry):
    def __init__(self, backoff_max=Retry.BACKOFF_MAX, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.BACKOFF_MAX = backoff_max

    def new(self, **kwargs):
        return super().new(backoff_max=self.BACKOFF_MAX, **kwargs)
```

If you do not override it, it will use the default parameter set in the `__init__()` definition.

And do not hesitate to test your solution with:

```
total=100
retry = RetryRequest(total=total, backoff_factor=0.1, backoff_max=77)

for i in range(0, total):
    print("Try #%d" % (total - retry.total + 1))
    retry = retry.increment()
    print(retry.get_backoff_time())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this worked for me:

```
class RetryRequest(Retry):
    def __init__(self, backoff_max=60, **kwargs):
    super(RetryRequest, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.BACKOFF_MAX = backoff_max
```

I don't think you need to override `get_backoff_time()`, simply overriding the constructor and setting `self.BACKOFF_MAX` should work.  Also, using `kwargs` lets you omit the other params.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the function override idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688687/4833737, a simpler version if you want it to apply globally:

```py
orig_backoff_fun = Retry.get_backoff_time

def custom_backoff_time(self):
    return min(5, orig_backoff_fun(self))

Retry.get_backoff_time = custom_backoff_time
```

Replace 5 with your desired max wait time.