# Exception with custom Retry class to set BACKOFF_MAX

Tags: python, python-requests

I've built a helper function and custom `Retry` class so I can set `BACKOFF_MAX` for a `requests` session as per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198708/11277108):

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry


class RetryRequest(Retry):

    def __init__(self, backoff_max: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.BACKOFF_MAX = backoff_max


def create_session(
    retries: int,
    backoff_factor: float,
    backoff_max: int,
    user_agent: str = "*",
    referer: str = None,
) -> Session:
    session = Session()
    retries_spec = RetryRequest(
        total=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        backoff_max=backoff_max,
    )
    session.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries_spec))
    headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent, "Referer": referer}
    session.headers.update(headers)
    return session
```

The `session` has been working fine for weeks but today it raised the following exception after it had been online for a few hours:

```
  File "/Users/username/GitHub/polgara/apis/base_endpoint.py", line 54, in _get
    response = self.client.session.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/capra_production/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/capra_production/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/capra_production/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/capra_production/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/capra_production/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/capra_production/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 581, in increment
    new_retry = self.new(
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/capra_production/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 338, in new
    return type(self)(**params)
TypeError: RetryRequest.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backoff_max'
```

It looks like something has gone awry in `requests` and it has tried to create a new session with the `RetryRequest` class but because it usually only deals with a `Retry` class it didn't pass the custom parameter of `backoff_max`.

I could get around this by setting a default argument for `backoff_max` but this defeats the object of being able to customise it when I create the session to begin with.

Would anyone have any idea on how I'd be able to solve this?

`requests` version is 2.28.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`increment` function in `Retry` is using `self.new` to create a new `retry`. This method doesn't have the `backoff_max` parameter, so it fails when trying to call `RetryRequest` `__init__()`.

To solve this issue you can override `new` in your custom class and set this parameter

```
class RetryRequest(Retry):

    def __init__(self, backoff_max: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MAX = backoff_max

    def new(self, **kwargs):
        return super().new(backoff_max=self.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MAX, **kwargs)
```

Note that I replaced `BACKOFF_MAX` with `DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MAX` since it's deprecated

```
warnings.warn(
    "Using 'Retry.BACKOFF_MAX' is deprecated and "
    "will be removed in v2.0. Use 'Retry.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MAX' instead",
    DeprecationWarning,
)
```